# How to get distinct values with inner join?

Tags: jquery, html, mysql

I have SQL select query with which I am using inner join and I get some values but with duplication. I want unique values and I am using DISTINCT, but it's not working.

```
select DISTINCT
  cy_affiliates_clickthroughs_tbl.*,
  cy_affiliates_tbl.email,
  cy_affiliates_tbl.firstname
from
  cy_affiliates_clickthroughs_tbl
  inner join cy_affiliates_tbl on
    cy_affiliates_clickthroughs_tbl.refid = cy_affiliates_tbl.referrer
where
  cy_affiliates_clickthroughs_tbl.refid = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'
  AND date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND date BETWEEN '$start_date'
  AND '$end_date'
ORDER BY date DESC", OBJECT;
```

I want to get distinct values of email and firstname.

Comment: can it populate more than 1 row data?
as possible that distinct of email & firstname aren't from the same row data

Comment: it should display distinct result via email id but its displaying me same one  rows data 4 times in the same table in frontend.-please check .Regards - Ankit

Comment: please copy and paste the result here of your current query

Comment: Name Email Date
anil anila876@gmail.com 2017-02-21
Gaurav gauravsharma2703@gmail.com 2017-02-21
ankit ankit@studioscue.in 2017-02-21
Gaurav gauravsharma2703@gmail.com 2017-02-21
ankit ankit@studioscue.in 2017-02-21
anil anila876@gmail.com 2017-02-21
Gaurav gauravsharma2703@gmail.com 2017-02-19
ankit ankit@studioscue.in 2017-02-19
anil anila876@gmail.com 2017-02-19
anil anila876@gmail.com 2017-02-19
Gaurav gauravsharma2703@gmail.com 2017-02-19
ankit ankit@studioscue.in 2017-02-19

Comment: Please update your original question with above clarification of your output, don't just stuff that in a single line comment ... Also output does not match your query?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `cy_affiliates_clickthroughs_tbl.*` from your select.

If you want to select only distinct email and first name, that's what you should have there.

There might be an issue in your where clause too, because `date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'` is wrong.
You probably meant `date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'`.

Answer (score -1):

You can get distinct values for name AND email by using GROUP BY:

```
select
  cy_affiliates_tbl.email,
  cy_affiliates_tbl.firstname,
  cy_affiliates_clickthroughs_tbl.*
from
  cy_affiliates_clickthroughs_tbl
  inner join cy_affiliates_tbl on
    cy_affiliates_clickthroughs_tbl.refid = cy_affiliates_tbl.referrer
where
  cy_affiliates_clickthroughs_tbl.refid = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'
  AND date BETWEEN '$start_date'
  AND '$end_date'
GROUP BY cy_affiliates_tbl.email, cy_affiliates_tbl.firstname
ORDER BY date DESC", OBJECT;
```

Note that you'll miss some of the results from cy_affiliates_clickthroughs_tbl to ensure the DISTINCT values for name and email.

Comment: no sir not working it displaying me nothing. please check again & reply me asap Thanks - Ankit

Comment: That's not how group by works; when using group by, all the columns in the select must be either aggregated with some function(like sum) or placed in the group by too

Comment: @stefano-zanini - pls test group by the way I mentioned. It does "work"  (without any group functions e.g sum) albeit not recommended as per the note in my response. Default behaviour in MySQL 5.7 imposes a restriction (that can be waived) where all columns in SELECT are required in GROUP BY but MySQL v5.6 or lower you can have columns in group by that are not in SELECT.

Comment: @user2579836 My bad, didn't know about this difference in MySQL versions. Sorry!